# For loop in assembly goes on forever

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The code below, the for loop will not stop looping the string. it goes on forever. But should only go on for how long the user inputs a number.

```
    segment .data 
  integer1: times 4 db 0 
heeder: db "%d", 0 
strin: db "Enter the number: ", 0
 segment .bss 



SECTION .text 
 global _main 

 extern _scanf 
 extern _printf 

 _main: 

    push integer1 ; address of integer1 (second parameter)
   push heeder ; arguments are right to left (first parameter)
   call _scanf
add esp, 8
mov eax, 0
mov eax, [integer1]

mov  ecx, eax




 loop:
 cmp eax, ecx 
 jbe for
 jmp end
 for:
 push strin
 call _printf
add esp, 4
 inc eax
      jmp loop
 end:
```

Can you get what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3):

After you call `printf()` the value in `eax` is the return value of the `printf` function - `eax` is not preserved by the call.

Note that even after you fix that problem, there's at least one other bug - `eax` and `ecx` start the loop with the same value - it looks like you want `eax1 to be set to 0, but you're doing that too soon.

Comment: In general, it's important in assembly to be aware of the registers preserved in the calling convention of any functions you call.  In cdecl calling convention, ecx is generally not preserved either.